# List of finance firms

Tags: finance

Is there a definite list of finance firms that I can download or scrape? I tried using python to scrape from [US News](https://money.usnews.com/financial-advisors/search?type=firm) but I couldn't access the server.

Comment: FINRA has a list of the their [member firms](https://www.finra.org/about/firms-we-regulate). This doesn't include asset managers that aren't organized as broker-dealers. It also only lists the BD component, which may be different from the normal name of the trading firm.

Comment: There are also a few firms in the [SBAI](http://www.sbai.org/signatories/). Neither of these lists includes auxiliary firms in the finance industry, like data vendors or software providers, for which there is tons of variety.

Comment: 'finance firms' may be too vague a term to be useful, can you be more specific?

Comment: @noob2 finance firms like 2sigma, Blackrock, MSCI etc. Portfolio management firms

Comment: MSCI is an interesting case because as an index provider they provide data to 2sigma, blackrock, etc. but they do not manage money themselves AFAIK. So they are not in same category as the 2 others. Nevertheless their decisions affect portfolios.